# Splitting lines at a specified distance and add attribute

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, linear-referencing

I have used QChainage to create points along a line every meter. What I am ultimately looking for, is to split the line layer along this point into segments with the chainage distance as an attribute. I use QGIS 2.6, but am open to options using GRASS standalone. I have installed the LRS plugin, but would like to know more about how to use to take me closer to my goals.

The QChainage gives me points on the line where these numbers are :

```
0-----1-----2-----3-----4-----5
```

I would like to split the line into segments where the QChainage points are and add the distance attribute to the segment.

```
|--1--|--2--|--3--|--4--|--5--|
```

I started tinkering with the GRASS v.lrs functions, but have not had success with it. I'm blocked by an error:

```
WARNING: Not enough points attached to the line
```

Comment: Not an expert so not giving an answer, but maybe this email exchange can help: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2007-December/042201.html

Comment: @Daniel I've seen that thread, but it hasn't gotten me further than I have with the v.lrs function.